# Flag Authorize.net Orders by Source

Tags: authorize.net

So I'm using the same authorize.net account for 2 websites.  Is there a way to flag where the source comes from to keep them seperated?

Comment: You should be careful when doing this. Visa and MasterCard guidelines require a separate merchant account for each website. If you get caught sharing it you run the list of having your funds held, account terminated, and blacklisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!

You may use the customer id, invoice number, or description to add the name of the source web site.

You may also want to look into the x_customer_ip field and set this to the web site ip address.

Hope this helps.